# Merge duplicate index and columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

i want to merge the duplicate index and column values in a dataframe and to not to drop there value, but to merge them to. For example:
df

```
  |A|A|B|B|C|D|
|A|0|1|0|0|0|0|
|A|1|0|0|0|0|0|
|B|0|0|0|1|0|1|
|B|0|0|1|0|0|0|
|C|0|0|0|0|1|0|
|D|0|0|1|0|0|1|
```

will be like df1

```
  |A|B|C|D|
|A|1|0|0|0|
|B|0|1|0|0|
|C|0|0|1|0|
|D|0|1|0|1|
```

does anyone has any idea

Comment: Can you explain what is the logic used for merging columns?

Comment: I have two dataframes, which i want to compare and they have different sizes,because the one dataframe has duplicated index and columns, but with different values. So if i want to compare them without using 4 for loops in total, is better first to get them to the same size, buy merging the columns and indexes with same names

Answer (score 3):

You can do two groupby's — one by the columns (`axis=1`), and one by the index, and get the max of each:

```
>>> df
   A  A  B  B  C  D
A  0  1  0  0  0  0
A  1  0  0  0  0  0
B  0  0  0  1  0  1
B  0  0  1  0  0  0
C  0  0  0  0  1  0
D  0  0  1  0  0  1

>>> df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).max().groupby(df.index).max()
   A  B  C  D
A  1  0  0  0
B  0  1  0  1
C  0  0  1  0
D  0  1  0  1
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it has not worked :/
I have a dataframe 421x421 elements which i want to compare with another with 208x208 elements. And the dataframe with 421 x 421 has the duplicated index and column names, but your answer did not merge them :( But thanks though!

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that! What went wrong?

Comment: I am not complete sure what went wrong, but i will try to find it out and tell u